# Mongodb Community v6.0 not running on mac iOS Ventura

Tags: mongodb, logfile

Just installed mongodb community v 6.0.5 on mac using Ventura iOS. This is my first time using mongodb. It installed fine and I can see the version, but when I try running it using the command:

```
mongod --dbpath ./database
```

it just prints out the log file...

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T14:45:18.991-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  
"id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T14:45:18.991-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        
"id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T14:45:18.991-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T14:45:18.991-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

It's much longer than that but I think you get the idea. My brew is up to date. What can I try differently?

Comment: You listed only the last 4 entries from the log, you would need a few more in order to see the actual error. I don't think `--dbpath ./database` is very smart, because it depends on the current directory. Better use the absolute path name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I ran `brew services list` my mongodb's status was listed as an 12288 error. Upon further [research](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unable-to-start-mongodb-community-error-12288/193538) I learned this means mongodb is already running (which is really confusing) and running the `mongo` or `mongosh` command in my terminal should bring up the mongo shell. For me, the `mongosh` command worked. Not sure how to tell which one will work on what devices, but thankfully there are only two to try from.

Comment: `mongo` is deprecated and `mongosh` is the replacement. See [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell)

Comment: When you install MongoDB as a service, then it is started automatically when you boot your computer. So, it is not really confusing.